# How do I view the built-in definition of TemplateBox styles in terms of low level boxes?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, boxes

The following:

```
TemplateBox[{"a", "b"}, "Binomial"] // RawBoxes
```

yields the correctly formatted (2d box structure) of Binomial[a,b]:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$$

But I would like to see its (and other built-in functions') explicit definition in terms of low level boxes.  Presumably, the definition of the style `"Binomial"` lives somewhere.  Where is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They live in stylesheets:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Binomial"}]
```

> ```
> {TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{"(", 
>     GridBox[{{#1}, {#2}}], ")"}] &), Tooltip -> Automatic}}
> ```